# Powershell XML Replace and Save Not Updating

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to update a config file using powershell. But the script is not updating the config file. Greatly appreciate any assistance on how to do this properly. Thank you!

```
#run.config
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
#<runmonth>201601</runmonth>
$actconfigpath = 'C:\Users\run.config'

#reportingmonth.txt
#201512
$rptmonth = Get-Content 'C:\Users\reportingmonth.txt' -First 1

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $actconfigpath
$node = $xml.runmonth
$xml.runmonth.Replace($node.ToString(),$rptmonth.toString())
$xml.Save($actconfigpath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$rptmonth = Get-Content 'C:\Users\reportingmonth.txt' -First 1
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $actconfigpath
$xml.runmonth = [string] $rptmonth
$xml.Save($actconfigpath)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!